# Summing integers

Tags: java, sum, integer

the instructions are: Enter an integer (32 bit) and sum its digits, you may be given a negative or positive integer. When reading in a negative integer, sum the digits but ignore the - sign.

this is what I have. Somehow I can't get it to ignore the negative signs when the integer is negative.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2_6M {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter amount
        System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
        int integer = input.nextInt();
        if (integer < 0)
            integer = -integer;

        // Calculations
        int rinteger = Math. abs (integer);
        int lastinteger = integer % 10;
        int X = integer / 10;
        int secondinteger= X % 10;
        int firstinteger = X /10;
        int finalinteger = firstinteger + secondinteger + lastinteger;


        // Display results
        System.out.println("Sum all digits in " + rinteger + " is " + finalinteger);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there an error? do you have an output?

Comment: This will work on a three digit number but in no other cases.

Comment: What @Mimisbrunnr said, you lack a loop in there.

Comment: It works fine for me (as long as your ints have 3 digits or less)

Comment: Copy and paste this: `import java.util.*;class S{public static void main(String[]a){Scanner i=new Scanner(System.in);while(true){int n=i.nextInt(),s=0;for(n=Math.abs(n);n!=0;s+=n%10,n/=10);System.out.println(s);}}}` (192 bytes) to a file named S.java, compile and run it. It should do everything you need and work correctly with arbitrary size ints.

Comment: Working demo: http://ideone.com/CCogm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the negative sign:

```
int integer = Math.abs(input.nextInt());
```

**Edit:**
I didn't notice that your code already did this. To make the code show the negative sign at the end, get rid of the following lines:

```
if (integer < 0)
        integer = -integer;
```

since you're already doing

```
int rinteger = Math. abs (integer);
```

Then, replace all instances other than the fist of `integer` in the calculations sections with rinteger, like this

```
    // Calculations
    int rinteger = Math. abs (integer);
    int lastinteger = rinteger % 10;
    int X = rinteger / 10;
    int secondinteger= X % 10;
    int firstinteger = X /10;
    int finalinteger = firstinteger + secondinteger + lastinteger;
```

Finally, when displaying the results, use integer instead of rinteger to restore the minus sign, or just put in a minus sign manually if `integer<0`.

Your code is also flawed if integer is more than 3 digits, as others have pointed out, but that's a separate issue.

To add more than 3 digits, you'll need a loop. Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise2_6M
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Create a Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Enter amount
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        int integer = input.nextInt();

        // Calculations
        int rinteger = Math. abs (integer);
        int sum = 0;
        int i=0;

        //loop through each digit (starting from the least significant) until the end of the number
        while(rinteger / Math.pow(10,i) > 0)
        {
            sum+=getDigit(rinteger,i);
            i++;
        }


        // Display results
        System.out.println("Sum all digits in " + integer + " is " + sum);
    }

    public static int getDigit(int num, int power)
    {
        return (num % (int)Math.pow(10,power+1)) / (int)Math.pow(10,power);
    }
}
```

Comment: then how do I do it to add more than three digits?

Comment: how come if the number such as -2147483648 is inputed... the outcome is 0?

Comment: @user972077 Because `Math.abs(-2147483648)` gives you the wrong result.

Comment: how can it give me the correct result? It all looks jibberish!

Comment: You can't store -2147483648 as an integer, an [int can only range](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) from [-2^31+1](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=-2%5E31-1) to [2^31-1](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=2%5E31-1). If you want to use extremely large/small numbers, learn about the [long](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/0120__Long.htm)

Comment: i have tried a million things and I can't get it. The code works for 75% of the assignment. How do I add to the code so it includes a long number?

Comment: Everywhere you see `int`, change it to `long`. Where you see `nextInt()`, change it to `nextLong()`.

Answer (score 4):

When I run it, it ignores the negatives just like it's supposed to. There are two problems I see.

1. When you print out for a negative number, it prints positive instead. Consider storing the original value for printing.
2. It doesn't work for large numbers because you hard code for 3 digits. Consider putting this in a loop to get all the digits.

Here's my test outputs:

The first is good, second is good, third should say "Sum all digits in -4 is 4", and last should say "Sum all digits in 12345 is 15".

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Exercise2_6M
Enter an integer:5
Sum all digits in 5 is 5

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Exercise2_6M
Enter an integer:100
Sum all digits in 100 is 1

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Exercise2_6M
Enter an integer:-4
Sum all digits in 4 is 4

C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Exercise2_6M
Enter an integer:12345
Sum all digits in 12345 is 132
```

Comment: `int s=0;for(n=Math.abs(n);n!=0;s+=n%10,n/=10);`, where `n` is the original number, and `s` will be the sum of all its digits. 46 chars

Answer (score -1):

I can't recall specifically, but integer might be a reserved java keyword, so you might want to change that variable name (i.e. inputInt  or something). The thought behind your code looks sounds... but instead of:

```
integer = -integer;
```

try:

```
inputInt = (-1)*inputInt;
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It's not a reserved word. And `-integer` works like it's supposed :)

Comment: integer is not a great name but it is works fine. Integer would have been a problem.

Comment: @Costis I don't think it would. (Strike that, I replaced `integer` with `Integer` and it ran just fine. So, I know it wouldn't be a problem.) At least to the compiler. To the person who has to read this code, yes that could be an issue!

Comment: I remember back in 2006 running into some issue by naming something Integer I believe... oh well. But @glowcoder you're right, readability might suffer from using naming that might be ambiguous with respect to native naming.